# Shopify GraphQL API: how do I get the return 'requested at' date?

Tags: shopify-api

The [returnCreate](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-04/mutations/returnCreate) mutation has DateTime parameter requestedAt, however the [Return](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-04/objects/Return#fields) object that I can query has no such field.
I need that to be able to calculate the number of days between the fullfilment and the return request.